# How can i change the Morphext rotating text color and size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Morphtext plugin. I want to change the text color and size of rotating text. CSS properties are not applying to those text. How can i achieve that?

Html code:

```
<h3>I am <span id="js-rotating"><span class="red">John</span>, <span class="blue">Sam</span>, <span class="yellow">Lee</span></span>
</h3>
```

This is CSS code:

```
.red {
        color: red;
    }

    .blue {
        color: blue;
    }

    .yellow {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

JS code:

```
<script>
    $("#js-rotating").Morphext({
        animation: "bounce",
        separator: ",",
        speed: 2000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS code please. It'll make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have added the code @pavger. Can you check now..?

Comment: Documentation for [Morphtext](https://github.com/MrSaints/Morphext) says: "If you would like to achieve a similar effect with more flexibility (e.g. out animation) and with HTML objects rather than text phrases (e.g. unordered list items), please check out [Morphist](https://github.com/MrSaints/Morphist)."